# im trying to remove an element from parallel arrays

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, function-definition

so I have 4 parallel arrays and I'm trying to remove one element from them at the same time and decrease the size of it it by one in the process, however there is something wrong with this code:

```
void removeAccount(char names[MAXSIZE][MAXSIZE], int stdID[MAXSIZE], float phones[MAXSIZE], int registrationYear[MAXSIZE])
{
    int ti;  // to save the student number entered from the keyboard.
    int tii; // to save the index of the entered student number.
    if (size <= 0)
    {
        printf("the list is empty\n");
    }
    printf("please enter a studnet number\n");
    scanf("%d", &ti);
    for (int f = 0; f < size; f++)
    {
        if (stdID[f] != ti)
        {
            printf("The student doesn't exists\n");
            printf("Please enter a student number\n");
            scanf("%d", &ti);
        }
        if (stdID[f] == ti)
        {
            tii = f;
            break;
        }
    }
    for (int v = tii - 1; v < size - 1; tii++)
    {
        strcpy(names[v], names[v + 1]);
        phones[v] = phones[v + 1];
        stdID[v] = stdID[v + 1];
        registrationYear[v] = registrationYear[v + 1];
    }
    size--;
```

Comment: Did you initialize your size variable? Cause I don't see it passed as a parameter....

Comment: For one, you're missing a loop in your input validation scheme. You should have an outer loop that takes an id from the user, and an inner loop that checks for that id, and if found, break BOTH loops. You're also in for a world of hurt in the compaction loop if/when the *first* slot (0) is the one discovered to contain the victim. Think about what `int v=tii-1` will start `v` as an index for when `tii` is `0`. That loop shoudl start at `tii`, not `tii-1`.

Comment: Why not a single array of structs?

Comment: @Asphodel it's a global variable.

Comment: @WhozCraig i will check that out and thank you for the heads up i didn't notice that xD

Comment: Fyi, if the list *order* does not have to be maintained you're doing a whole lot of work for nothing in that compaction loop. You could instead just snag the *last* elements in your arrays (assuming there is still at least one left *past* the point where you're removing) and dump them into the slots occupied by the items you're removing, then reduce size by one (the latter you're already doing). If removing the *last* element, then just the size reduction will suffice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For starters it is a bad design of a function when the function depends on a global variable as your function depends on the global variable `size`.

This code snippet

```
printf("please enter a studnet number\n");
scanf("%d", &ti);
for (int f = 0; f < size; f++)
{
    if (stdID[f] != ti)
    {
        printf("The student doesn't exists\n");
        printf("Please enter a student number\n");
        scanf("%d", &ti);
    }
    if (stdID[f] == ti)
    {
        tii = f;
        break;
    }
}
```

does not make a sense.

Instead you should write

```
int pos;

do
{
    printf("please enter a student number\n");
    scanf("%d", &ti);

    pos = 0;

    while ( pos < size && stdID[pos] != ti ) ++pos;

    if ( pos == size )
    {
        printf("The student doesn't exists\n");
    }
} while ( pos == size );
```

This for loop

```
for (int v = tii - 1; v < size - 1; tii++)
{
    strcpy(names[v], names[v + 1]);
    phones[v] = phones[v + 1];
    stdID[v] = stdID[v + 1];
    registrationYear[v] = registrationYear[v + 1];
}
```

is also incorrect.

It should look like

```
while ( ++pos < size )
{
    strcpy(names[pos - 1], names[pos]);
    phones[pos - 1] = phones[pos];
    stdID[pos - 1] = stdID[pos];
    registrationYear[pos - 1] = registrationYear[pos];
}
```